# Know the IP - address of devices that downloaded my app and create unique id for devices

Tags: android, tracking

I have an app that will be launched soon. I also have a database where I want to insert the ip address and create a unique id for each device that has downloaded or installed my app..I just want to know if I should create a separate activity for this?.. And should it be my LAUNCHER?.. if yes, how do I go about showing my splashscreen??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to establish a simple HttpConnection with your server so that your server could capture your ip and save it in the database. Make a class that extends asyncTask and do the HttpConnection thingy in `doInBackground()` function.
Edit : By 'capture', I mean You can get the ip using `getLocalHost` on your device and send it to a php page on the server. Have a page that simply receives it and store it in a database if that ip 'does not exist'.

Comment: is this done with a separate activity? and should i set this activity as my launcher?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can make your mainActivity extend asyncTask. But remember, asyncTask is meant only for simple background operations(like what you're trying now). If you wish to perform Long running tasks, you've to go for a Handler. Good luck